# Magento2.3: Order not Place and Redirect to checkout/cart page

Tags: magento2.3, redirect, order-success-page

I have upload my Magento2.3 site on site ground. Others things are working fine but **order not place** redirect to checkout cart page.

system.log:

```
 [2019-04-19 12:15:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'div.sidebar.main' tries to reorder itself towards 'main', but their parents are different: 'div.sidebar' and 'div.col-main' respectively. [] []
    [2019-04-19 12:15:47] main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'currency' tries to reorder itself towards 'store_language', but their parents are different: 'header.panel' and 'theme_header' respectively. [] []
```

live site link

https://rcg.com.pk/

But same project working fine on staging site.

http://rcg.staging.techgaragenow.com

It hosted on digital ocean .Working fine every thing .kindly describe the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something wrong with your email decrypt. Check following code in your side that is comes from your live site.

```
Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 39 in /home/rcg40548/public_html/vendor/pelago/emogrifier/Classes/Emogrifier.php on line 1507

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\Framework\Encryption\Adapter\SodiumChachaIetf::decrypt() must be of the type string, bool returned in /home/rcg40548/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Adapter/SodiumChachaIetf.php:68 Stack trace: #0 /home/rcg40548/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Encryptor.php(358): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Adapter\SodiumChachaIetf->decrypt('\x8F\e\xDA\xE7\r:\xBA\x1F%\xE2sZ\vX~...') #1 /home/rcg40548/public_html/app/code/Mageplaza/Smtp/Helper/Data.php(81): Magento\Framework\Encryption\Encryptor->decrypt('jxva5w06uh8l4nN...') #2 /home/rcg40548/public_html/app/code/Mageplaza/Smtp/Mail/Rse/Mail.php(138): Mageplaza\Smtp\Helper\Data->getPassword('1') #3 /home/rcg40548/public_html/app/code/Mageplaza/Smtp/Mail/Transport.php(110): Mageplaza\Smtp\Mail\Rse\Mail->getTransport('1') #4 /home/rcg40548/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(135): Mageplaza\Smtp\Mail\Transport->aroundSendMessage(Object(Magento\Email\Model\Transport\Interce in /home/rcg40548/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Encryption/Adapter/SodiumChachaIetf.php on line 68
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Fatal Error: 'Uncaught TypeError: Return value of Magento\\Framework\\Encryption\\Adapter\\SodiumChachaIetf::decrypt() must be of the type string, bool returned in \/home\/rcg40548\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Encryption\/Adapter\/SodiumChachaIetf.php:68\nStack trace:\n#0 \/home\/rcg40548\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Encryption\/Encryptor.php(358): Magento\\Framework\\Encryption\\Adapter\\SodiumChachaIetf->decrypt('\\x8F\\e\\xDA\\xE7\\r:\\xBA\\x1F%\\xE2sZ\\vX~...')\n#1 \/home\/rcg40548\/public_html\/app\/code\/Mageplaza\/Smtp\/Helper\/Data.php(81): Magento\\Framework\\Encryption\\Encryptor->decrypt('jxva5w06uh8l4nN...')\n#2 \/home\/rcg40548\/public_html\/app\/code\/Mageplaza\/Smtp\/Mail\/Rse\/Mail.php(138): Mageplaza\\Smtp\\Helper\\Data->getPassword('1')\n#3 \/home\/rcg40548\/public_html\/app\/code\/Mageplaza\/Smtp\/Mail\/Transport.php(110): Mageplaza\\Smtp\\Mail\\Rse\\Mail->getTransport('1')\n#4 \/home\/rcg40548\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php(135): Mageplaza\\Smtp\\Mail\\Transport->aroundSendMessage(Object(Magento\\Email\\Model\\Transport\\Interce' in '\/home\/rcg40548\/public_html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Encryption\/Adapter\/SodiumChachaIetf.php' on line 68","trace":"Trace is not available."}]}}
```

Comment: from where you get the warning ? console ? or where?